# Swift 3 - Pass Dictionary inside Array from JSON to Another Method

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, swift3

I have the following JSON:

```
{  
   "stores":2,
   "store_data":[  
      {  
         "store_id":1,
         "store_name":"Target"
         "store_color":"000000"
      },
      {  
         "store_id":2,
         "store_name":"Walmart"
         "store_color":"FFFFFF"
      }
   ]
}
```

And I am collecting it (within a function) the following way (safeguards removed for simplicity):

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: baseURL) { (data, response, error) in
    if let tmpRawData: NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary {
        process(rawData: tmpRawData)
    }
}
```

And sending it to the helper process function defined as:

```
func process(rawData: NSDictionary) -> Bool {
    if let storeDataArray = rawData["store_data"] {
        // Here I want to loop through the store_data array 
    }
}
```

And I am having some trouble looping through the array in the function above.  Initially, I had tried:

```
for store: Dictionary<String, String> in storeDataArray {
    // Do things with store["store_id"] here
}
```

But I am new to swift and am having trouble deciphering between NSArray, Array, Dictionary, NSDictionary, etc.  I'm working in Swift 3.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't annotate types that much. The compiler will tell you if it needs an explicit annotation

Second of all it's convenient to declare a type alias for a JSON dictionary

```
typealias JSONObject = [String:Any]
```

This is the task, `tmpRawData` is a dictionary – represented by `{}` in the JSON.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: baseURL) { (data, response, error) in
  if let tmpRawData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! JSONObject {
    process(rawData: tmpRawData)
  }
}
```

and the `process` function, the type alias makes everything more readable.
The value of `rawData` is an array of dictionaries – represented by `[]` in the JSON.

```
func process(rawData: JSONObject) -> Bool {
  if let storeDataArray = rawData["store_data"]  as? [JSONObject] {
    for store in storeDataArray {
      let storeID = store["store_id"] as! Int
      let storeName = store["store_name"] as! String
      let storeColor = store["store_color"] as! String
     print(storeID, storeName, storeColor)
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea why all tutorials suggests the `mutableContainers` option. You don't need it at all in Swift when using native collection types.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! I thought I was being overly explicit...thanks!